# Angular bootstrap alerts from service

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am having a service, that listens to incoming events.
If such an event happens, I want to notify the user.
At the moment, I am using `alert()`.

I want that, in every component, if the service triggers, a Bootstrap-alert pop-ups.

Is there anything to do that?
(I am also using prime-ng, if there is something for that but no material)

So what I really want is kind of an "custom alert", and whenever I call the `alertService.alert(string)` a pop up appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply implement `ngx-toastr` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr?activeTab=readme).

Then, use global styles for **Bootstrap** as written in the documentation:

```
// bootstrap style toast
// or import a bootstrap 4 alert styled design (SASS ONLY)
// should be after your bootstrap imports, it uses bs4 variables, mixins, functions
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';
// if you'd like to use it without importing all of bootstrap it requires
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins';
// bootstrap 4
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';
// boostrap 5
@import 'ngx-toastr/toastr-bs5-alert';
```

After importing `ToastrModule` and `ToastrService` ([see the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr?activeTab=readme)), It will be very easy to use:

```
this.toastrService.error('everything is broken', 'Major Error', {
  timeOut: 3000,
});
```

Also, you can use [Angular Bootstrap Toast](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview), It's a little more difficult and you have to write more code. But **it's more customizable**.

You can see [Toast management service example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/examples) to use **Bootstrap Toast** as service.